# How to ask people to help after you have filled in a wrong number

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context

Here is the situation.

I was browsing some clothes on a web sites. Some time later, I decided to make the order for some lace ones.  So, I was then asked to fill in the order form. 
I might be sleepy that I added an extra digit to my contact number in the order form.   Say, the correct contact number should be 123456789, but I mistakenly filled in the wrong one, 1234567890.  And I did not carefully check the information before I pressed the submit button.

Two days have passed after this happened, and now I am trying to call the customer service department for help, but I am not sure if it will sound weird if I use the word, "update" in this sentence.

> "I need your help to **update** my contact number"

Or the word, "Update" is readable in computers only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb *update* is fine, but that usually means that you are changing a number from an older valid number to a newer one.

You could use the verb *correct* instead:

> "I need your help to **correct** my contact number"

This would mean that the number they have in the system now is incorrect, whereas using *update* could mean the current number was correct at one time but is now changing.

That said, either word should work just fine for you. When dealing with a problem like this, most people don't pay too much attention to subtle differences like these, and your use of the word *update* would be just fine in this case.